# How could know if a string is included in a tab url with a Chrome extension v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to create a Chrome extension that watch tabs url and trigger an action when the tab url includes  "ftp://" and some data afterlike "ftp://user&pass"

This repository include an interesting example for v2 (pageaction_by_url)(it detects when there is a 'g' in the tab url), but it does not work in actual Chrome version

https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/pageaction_by_url

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

I can´t found examples to manifest version 3 to learn how to develope it.

Any idea where to start? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the action you want to trigger. Describe it in more detail.

Comment: I want to take user and pass params of URL (only when URL begin by ftp:// ) and do things. For example conect to a server and show remote info in an iframe

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't open ftp pages so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Could I use an invented prefix protocol? For example, myftp:// ? Its only an identifier to know when and what user and pass extension need to get

Comment: Chrome can't show custom protocols, but you can probably register your extension as a handler by using navigator.registerProtocolHandler. I didn't use it myself though so I can't help further.